# summarize(n()) and count() difficulties in R

Tags: r, dplyr, count, summarize

This problem is driving me crazy and I can't figure it out. Here is a subset of my dataframe (df) to make things easier.

[image]

I want to group_by sex and count the total. Simple?

```
df %>% group_by(sex) %>% count()
```

This code returns the following output

[image]

What I wanted (and what I thought this code did when I used it before (maybe my memory is bad) was this output

[image]

I obtained this output using

```
df %>% group_by(sex) %>% tally()
```

I have nothing against tally() but I swear I was using count() before.

Also, I thought I could use group_by %>% summarize(n()) to get the same result, but when I try this code

```
df %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarize(n())
```

I get this message

[image]

Again, I 'thought' this would work and produce similar output, but it's not. Maybe I'm misremembering things and the least you can do is tell me to get my memory checked :-D

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using `df %>% group_by(sex) %>% dplyr::count()` you might have `plyr` loaded in your session.

Comment: Also please don't add data as images, share them in a reproducible format using which we can test the solution. We cannot copy data from an image.

Comment: @RonakShah Strangely, when I copy and past the code you give, it works fine. I already had dplyr loaded. I loaded it again just in case. Same result as my earlier problem.

Comment: you also have `plyr` loaded which masks functions `summarise` and `count`. Restart R and load only `dplyr`.

Comment: I restarted R and tried it. It worked. Thank you. I had plyr and dplyr both loaded for that session. That must be why. So, having both libraries loaded in the same session can cause certain issues like this?

Answer (score 0):

if you want output like this

[image]

add column name before your `n()` function. here's the example

```
df %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarize(num_of_sex = n())
```

Comment: The solution was found, thanks. It was due to having plyr and dplyr both loaded in the session. The code you provided works now.